# Npm install creates empty folders in node_modules

Tags: npm, npm-install

It happens randomly. Running npmp install again doesn't seem to fix this issue. I have to destroy node_modules folder and run npm install again. Anybody knows what is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `package.json` file. You might have not created dependency correctly. I had same issue. After adding =>

```
 "dependencies" : {
    "express"    : "~4.7.2",
    "mongoose"   : "~3.6.2",
    "morgan"     : "~1.2.2",
    "body-parser": "~1.5.2",
    "method-override": "~2.1.2"
    }
```

Now its working fine.